# How can I get attribute value?

Tags: jquery, dropdown

I need to get the attribute value on `<li>`, I am using the following plugin:
*Searchable Multi-select Dropdown Plugin With jQuery - Dropdown.js*

How can I get the attribute value of each li when all  changes to ul li?

Here is HTML:

```
<option value="D12320010">MV/LV Fault Recovery</option>
          <option value="2">a</option>
          <option value="3">a1</option>
          <option value="4">dfg</option>
          <option value="5">sdsdf</option>
          <option value="6">a8</option>
```

JS:

```
$('.demo').dropdown({
      multipleMode: 'label'
  })
```

HTML rendered after plugin changes my `<option>` to `<li>`

```
<div class="dropdown-main">
  <ul>
    <li tabindex="0" data-value="D12320010" class="dropdown-option ">MV/LV Fault Recovery</li>
    <li tabindex="0" data-value="2" class="dropdown-option ">a</li>
    <li tabindex="0" data-value="3" class="dropdown-option ">a1</li>
    <li tabindex="0" data-value="4" class="dropdown-option ">dfg</li>
    <li tabindex="0" data-value="5" class="dropdown-option ">sdsdf</li>
    <li tabindex="0" data-value="6" class="dropdown-option ">a8</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no `li` in your example

Comment: by using the above mentioned plugin, it changes my <option> to <li>

Comment: @Cid Look now, edited

Comment: As usual $( ".target" ).change(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});

Comment: @VipinKumarSoni Not working, i think because its not have <li> by default.. Default is select and options, then it changes to ul and li

Comment: can you create a snippet or fiddle with this plugin, so we can test and debug to try to help?

Comment: @CalvinNunes In a nutshell I need to know that how can i write my own code after binding of library function:
$('.demo').dropdown({
      multipleMode: 'label'
  })

Comment: So, my code will run after library function binding successfully.

Comment: I found "choice" callback there: $('.demo').dropdown({
      multipleMode: 'label',
      choice: function () {
      
      }
  }); https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown.html

Comment: I understood your question, I'm just asking for a snippet or fiddle

Comment: @CalvinNunes please find the link
https://jsfiddle.net/Umair45/z7tvhogn/

Comment: @VipinKumarSoni still not getting desired thing, you can also check the fiddle link.Would be grateful for the help!

Comment: the link you provided doesn't have any library loaded, so I can't reproduce, please add the libraries you're using (jquery and dropdown) then I can really reproduce and debug

Comment: First example here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Searchable-Multi-select-jQuery-Dropdown/
do not have online links of libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `choice` callback option when initializing the dropdown:

```
$('.demo').dropdown({
    multipleMode: 'label',
    choice: function () {
        $('.demo').find(':selected').each(function( index ) {
          console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
        });
    }
});
```